# How to define many arguments in function?

Tags: functions, function-construction

Following is my code, you can see that in eq[], its arguments are defined by `t` and `list{xs}`, If I expand the `list{xs}`, I have to write a lot of `λ`.
Could you help me to simplify the definition of eq[]? 
When I wanna set λ from λ1 to λ1000, how can I achieve that?

````
Clear[n, λs, xs, tvalues]
n = 5;
λs = Symbol["λ" <> ToString[#]] & /@ Range[n](*number of sites*);
xs = Append[λs, β];
tvalues = Range[0., 1., 0.01] (*set of t values*);
randnum = RandomReal[1, {10, n + 1}];

Clear[eq]
eq[t_, {λ1_, λ2_, λ3_, λ4_, λ5_, β_}] = 
  Block[{U = 1., μ = 0.5, ϵ = (-2 t - 0.5), EE, summand},

   EE[k_] := (-2  t ( Cos[(2 π  (k - 1))/n])) - μ;
   summand[λ_, k_] := (U/(2 n)) (Cosh[λ]^2 Sinh[λ]^2 + 
        2 Sinh[λ]^4 + 
        2 β^2 Cosh[λ] Sinh[λ] + 
        4 β^2 Sinh[λ]^2 ) + Sinh[λ]^2 EE[k];
   Total[MapIndexed[summand[#, #2[[1]]] &, λs]] + ( β^2 ϵ) + (U/(2 n)) (β^4)
 ];

```
````

Comment: Use constructs of the form `x[i]` instead of forcing `x1, x2,... ` with `ToString`. The let the function accept a `List` argument, instead of specifying the elements of the list explicitly in the argument pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define your function using the following (note also the `:=`):

```
eq[t_, {lambdas__, β_}] := (* rest of your code *)
```

then inside the code change `λs` in `MapIndexed[summand[#, #2[[1]]] &, λs]]` to

```
MapIndexed[summand[#, #2[[1]]]&, List[lambdas]]]
```

Comment: Thanks, it is working.